# How do you access the console of a GCE VM instance?

Tags: console, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine

How can I access the console of a Google Compute Engine VM instance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To see the console output (read-only), you can use any of the following methods:

- Web UI via [Developers Console](https://cloud.google.com/console) – on the instance detail page, scroll to the bottom of the page and expand the console output view
- CLI via [`gcloud compute instances get-serial-port-output`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/get-serial-port-output)
- API via [`getSerialPortOutput`](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/latest/instances/getSerialPortOutput)

To get read/write (interactive) access, follow instructions on [this page](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console):

> ```
> gcloud compute instances add-metadata [INSTANCE_NAME] \
>     --metadata=serial-port-enable=1
> ```

and then, per [the same page](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console), either connect via Google Cloud Console:

> Go to the VM instances page.
>
> 1. Go to the [GCE VM instances page](https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/instances)
> 2. Click the instance you want to connect to.
> 3. Scroll to the bottom of the page and look for the **Serial port** section.
> 4. If you want to connect to a serial port other than the default serial port 1, click the down arrow next to the **Connect to serial port** button and change the port number accordingly.
> 5. Click the **Connect to serial port** button to connect to port 1 by default. For Windows instances, pull down the dropdown menu next to the button and connect to **Port 2** to access the serial console.

or, connect via `gcloud`:

> Use the `gcloud compute connect-to-serial-port` subcommand to connect using the `gcloud` command-line tool. For example:
>
> ```
> gcloud compute connect-to-serial-port [INSTANCE_NAME]
> ```
>
> where `[INSTANCE_NAME]` is the name of the instance for which you want to access the serial console.
>
> By default, the `connect-to-serial-port` command connects to port 1 of the serial console. If you are connecting to a Windows VM instance, connect to port 2 instead:
>
> ```
> gcloud compute connect-to-serial-port [INSTANCE_NAME] --port 2
> ```
>
> To connect to any other port, provide a different port number using the `--port` flag. You can provide a port number from 1 through 4, inclusively. To learn more about port numbers, see [Understanding serial port numbering](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console#understanding_serial_port_numbering).

Answer (score 1):

While this doesn't answer your direct question, if the reason you need physical console access is to troubleshoot why a system is inaccessible (i.e. it no longer boots or, because of a bad firewall configuration, you can no longer access it over SSH), your best bet is to:

1. Update the disk configuration so it is not deleted when the instance is destroyed
2. Delete the instance so the disk is no longer attached to a running instance
3. Attach the disk to another instance which boots correctly
4. Mount the disk to a temporary location within that instance, so you can read logs, view/edit configuration files, etc.

Comment: Hmm ok. Sounds like a complete headache. Rackspace, VMware all provide console. Seems a strange way of doing it.