# ssh and gateway error in europe-west1-b while using free trial on GCP

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am using a trial version and have 30 days remaining for trial period.
I have setup a HDP 2.2 cluster using bdutil, was working fine until Feb 12, 2015.
Since then, I'm facing browser based SSH (unable to connect to port 22 ) and gateway error for all the nodes.

The Cluster is in Europe region. I have configured the network settings but still facing the problem. This is a HDP setup using bdutil. It has 4 instance of machine type n1-highmem-2 (2 vCPU, 13 GB memory). As of today (15-feb-2015) it shows $180.34 and 29 days left.

Has anyone came across this issue recently?
How can I troubleshoot further and resolve the issue?

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/gce-discussion/gqQ0JAmOrGw/RbB3kxpf2jUJ

Serial ouput of an instance:

```
Welcome to CentOS 

Starting udev: udevd[329]: can not read '/etc/udev/rules.d/75-persistent-net-generator.rules'
udevd[329]: can not read '/etc/udev/rules.d/75-persistent-net-generator.rules'
udev: starting version 147
piix4_smbus 0000:00:01.3: SMBus base address uninitialized - upgrade BIOS or use force_addr=0xaddr
sd 0:0:1:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
sd 0:0:2:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
%G[  OK  ]
Setting hostname localhost:  [  OK  ]
Setting up Logical Volume Management:   No volume groups found
[  OK  ]
Checking filesystems
Checking all file systems.
[/sbin/fsck.ext4 (1) -- /] fsck.ext4 -a /dev/sda1 
/dev/sda1: clean, 102574/655360 files, 1822213/2620928 blocks
[/sbin/fsck.ext3 (1) -- /datafs] fsck.ext3 -a /dev/sdb1 
/dev/sdb1: clean, 21/32768000 files, 2107267/131070310 blocks
[/sbin/fsck.ext4 (1) -- /mnt/pd1] fsck.ext4 -a /dev/sdb 
/dev/sdb: One or more block group descriptor checksums are invalid.  FIXED.
/dev/sdb: Group descriptor 880 checksum is invalid.  
/dev/sdb: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY.
    (i.e., without -a or -p options)
%GGive root password for maintenance
(or type Control-D to continue):
```

Comment: There might be something wrong on the VM instances themselves that's preventing external connections. Do you see anything in the [VM's console output](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27746205/3618671)?

Comment: @Misha, tried both using browser based ssh and starter kit i am facing the same problem "Connection FailedWe are unable to connect to the VM on port 22. " while accessing through browser based ssh  and using starter kit  , it gives return code 255. So i am unable to view the VM's console output. Also running the command gcloud compute --project YOUR-PROJECT instances list it shows the instances in running status. Also the certain credits are debited daily as per resource consumption.

Comment: @Misha, i have edited the question and included additional details. Please have a look and reply your suggestion.

Comment: Could you try the following steps for one instance and check if they solve the issue? 

1- Take a snapshot of the Persistent Disk . 
2- You'll need to delete the instance while **not** deleting the boot disk because you have reached the cores quota for Free Trial users. In order to make sure you don't delete your boot disk when you delete the instance, go to the instance in the Developer's Console, and uncheck the box that says "Delete boot disk when instance is deleted". 
3- Boot a new VM using that snapshot. 
4- Run fsck from there.

Comment: @adrian , i followed the steps but still unable to ssh to run the fsck .

Comment: @PratikShah can you follow the instructions on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28156597/3618671) to detach the disk, create a separate new VM (with its own disk), and then mount this disk as an additional disk to run fsck on it?

Comment: @PratikShah I'm not sure what "starter kit" is, can you clarify? It's unclear why there's an issue with the partitions: have you manually repartitioned the disk or ran tools that repartition the disk? It appears that the partition table may have been corrupted. Are you running custom setup scripts, Chef, Puppet, etc.? Can you recreate those instances if necessary?